# getting reflect.Value(&foo) from reflect.Value(foo)

Tags: go, pointers, reflection

the title of the question pretty much sums it up. I'm playing with reflections using Go, and I'm trying to get the address of what reflect.Value() is pointing at.

why?

I have a function that can receive a struct in two ways:
first.. this is the struct

```
type UserInfo struct {
    Name   string        `json:"name"`
    Roles  *[]model.Role `json:"role"`
    UserId int           `json:"user_id" db:"id"`
}
```

one:

```
var userInfo types.UserInfo
myFunc(&userInfo)
```

with this method i'm good since since it's a pointer to a struct that has it's memory allocated

the 2nd method:

```
var userInfo *types.UserInfo
myFunc(userInfo)
```

so here if I do `reflect.Value()` it's a Nil Pointer.
i want to allocate that struct and to point userInfo to the new place.
now I can easily do that if I paste &userInfo as well
and perform:

```
myFunc(dst interface{}, dstAddr interface{})
{
 v := reflect.ValueOf(dstAddr)
 t := reflect.TypeOf(dst)
 ptr := reflect.New(t.Type())
 ...
 v.Elem().Set(ptr)
}
```

now I would except that `reflect.ValueOf(dst).Addr()` will be the same as `reflect.ValueOf(&dst)` but actually `reflect.ValueOf(dst).CanAddr()` returns false.

so.. is there a way to get `reflect.ValueOf(&dst)` while only having `reflect.ValueOf(dst)` ?

Comment: You can't get `reflect.Value(&foo)` from `reflect.Value(foo)`, the `foo` you pass will be a copy, and you could only get the address of the copy, not that of the original.

Comment: @icza - what I'm trying to achieve is to get only one parameter. and if i'm only sending reflect.Value(&foo), the reflect.Value(&foo).Elem() should be Reflect.Value(foo) correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whatever you pass to [`reflect.ValueOf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#ValueOf) or any other function, a copy will be made.

That being said, `reflect.Value(foo)` cannot possibly give you back the address of the original `foo`, it could only give you back the address of the copy. To avoid further confusion, in this case [`Value.CanAddr()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.CanAddr) would return `false`, letting you know the address that *could* be returned using [`Value.Addr()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Addr) would not be what most would expect, it wouldn't be a *useful* address.

As you indicated, you want to pass a *single* value, so pass `&foo`. Doing so you will be able to get the `foo` value pointed by `&foo` using [`Value.Elem()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Elem).

Also note that the (wrapped) `foo` value you get by `Value.Elem()` will be addressable, since it was acquired from a `reflect.Value` wrapping `&foo`. So if the `reflect.Value` is **not** `reflect.ValueOf(foo)` but `reflect.ValueOf(&foo).Elem()`, you are able to get back (to) `&foo`.

See this example:

```
func main() {
    var foo = 3

    fmt.Println("Address:", &foo)
    bar(&foo)
    fmt.Println("After:", foo)
}

func bar(x interface{}) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(x)

    v2 := v.Elem()
    fmt.Println("Passed pointed value:", v2.Interface())
    v2.Set(reflect.ValueOf(4))

    fmt.Println("Address got from pointed value:", v2.Addr())
}
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/uMh8k98FkQi)):

```
Address: 0xc000080010
Passed pointed value: 3
Address got from pointed value: 0xc000080010
After: 4
```